# Debian 8 iptables blocked all connections

Tags: linux, networking, debian, firewall, iptables

I've got a really big problem with my root server running Debian 8 (64-Bit). I installed some iptables rules to block specific IP ranges belonging to China and some blacklisted ranges. It seems that something went wrong and the server isn't reachable through SSH, HTTP and so on.

I can get root shell access to the server through the KVM console provided by my hoster. But I don't get how to allow the connections now. I followed some tutorials on the internet to flush the iptables but it didn't work, so I ended up uninstalling iptables.

But it still doesn't work. I'm not even able to install any package through `apt-get` because it throws an fetch error.

Comment: Did you reboot? When you get out of this, use UFW  (UncomplicatedFireWall), it's a simplified and much more usable layer over IPTables,

Comment: yes. I reboot a couple of times. Did you know if its necessary to have iptables installed ? Maybe is the problem that ive uninstalled it.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules

Comment: i dont have iptables installed and im not able to install it

Comment: Did you boot from a live CD and manually download the [`iptables` package](https://packages.debian.org/de/jessie/iptables) as I suggested yesterday? Check if the dependencies are still installed, otherwise you need to download whatever's missing too. If you cannot install the  downloaded package with `dpkg` (after rebooting into the normal system) please update your question with the output from the `dpkg` statement.

Comment: And yes, you need `iptables` for managing the firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a need to configure iptables on the remote host.
Often, the correct iptables rules can be obtained with some use of the pump method and against such cases one must be insured.
Here I will describe how to configure iptables so painlessly that in the case of blocking access to itself, this access could be obtained again.

The idea is this: in the cron we write down a rule that at a certain point in time will reset the iptables rules.
That is, suppose I came up with a chain of rules and applied it, and suddenly the connection to the remote host suddenly stopped. However, before that, we added a script to cron that will clear all the rules and access to the remote server can be obtained again.

Important!
Iptables rules are applied immediately after execution.
For example, if you enter:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Then the connection on ssh will be lost immediately.

Create a script that will clear all iptables rules:

```
# vim /etc/restore_iptables.conf
#!/bin/sh
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
# remove all rules
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
# allow all connections
$IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

You also need to make the script executable:

```
# chmod +x /etc/restore_iptables.conf
```

The script should be run immediately after the network interfaces are up, in Debian it's enough to add the line like this:

```
# vim /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
   pre-up /etc/iptables.conf
```

Now add the rule to cron to run our backup recovery script every five minutes, for example:

```
# crontab -e
*/5 * * * * /etc/restore_iptables.conf
```

Now we can test the new rules.
To do this, create a file with test rules, for example:

```
# vim /etc/test_iptables.conf
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
$IPT -F
$IPT -X
# we get a mistake and drop ssh connection
$IPT -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -j DROP
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p TCP --sport 22 -j DROP
```

Run it:

```
# chmod +x /etc/test_iptables.conf
# /etc/test_iptables.conf
```

With such rules, we will immediately drop the connection on ssh. However, we took everything into account, it's enough to wait 5 minutes and you can reconnect.

After you are sure that all the rules work as needed, you need to remove or comment out the rule in cron:

```
# crontab -e
#*/5 * * * * /etc/restore_iptables.conf
```

And copy the new rule file instead of our backup:

```
# cat /etc/test_iptables.conf > /etc/restore_iptables.conf
```

Be attentive!